# iDRAC 6 Express and Ubuntu Linux 10.04 LTS Server

Tags: ubuntu, dell, drac

I have a Dell R610 server with the iDRAC 6 Express remote management extention. The problem is that this thing is using the NIC1 interface in some kind of shared mode. Dell is talking about NIC teaming which should be enabled on the operating system side. On Windows this is managed by the Boardcom Software if I'm correct but I have no idea to enable this with Ubuntu Linux 10.04 LTS.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of setup. I'm sure there is a easy solution but I just can't figure out why I can't reach the iDRAC via the ip address I set up. Next time I will buy the server with the Enterprise version of iDRAC which has a dedicated NIC.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the iDRAC 6 Express doesn't actually provide remote control functionality, only remote monitoring and remote power management (to power cycle, power off, etc.).  Might not be worth the effort to setup.

Comment: (Removed my comment after re-reading your question). Maybe it's sending with a VLAN tag. You could connect the monitored port to a switch with monitoring capability and run wireshark on the monitoring port. This should help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: This link http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smdrac3/idrac/idrac11mono/en/ug/html/racugc1.htm#wp51580 shows that there is no virtual console, but IPMI should still provide a serial console over the network. Not the same, but still helpful.

Comment: @AndreasM Yeah - likely a vlan tag.  christianwolff Check the iDRAC's network config to see if it's configured with a vlan.

Answer (score 1):

If this works like the iDRAC6 Enterprise it uses VLAN tagging for sure.

Can`t you install OMSA and check the setup of the iDRAC6 express?

Answer (score 0):

Simple hack, but doesn't really address the problem. Use NIC2 for networking and NIC1 for iDRAC.  Also if you're using shared, both the IP for the network device and the iDRAC would probably need to be on the the same network/vlan.